# Classic ASP - Custom Error Pages

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, custom-error-pages

I have a clean install of Windows Server 2008 with IIS7. There I installed "Classic ASP" and the changed the debugging option "Send Errors To Browser" to True.

**1.**

I created a directory with 2 files:

```
-- C:\inetpub\wwwroot\stadtbibliothek
 - index.asp -> <% Response.Write "Hello World" %>
 - 500-100.asp -> <% Response.Write "Error" %>
```

I konverted the directory to an application and assigned a application pool i created (.net version: no managed code, pipelinecode: classic).

Then I tested the page from an remote client (http://svr-name.domain/stadtbibliothek/) and "Hello World" showed up.

**2.**

I added an error to the index.asp file and a web.config file to the "stadtbibliothek" folder (there is none in the root):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.asp" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
                <httpErrors>
                    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" />
                    <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
                </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Solution:**

Turned out I just needed to include the folder name to the path:

`<error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/stadtbibliothek/error.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />`

**Thanks for your suggestions!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689487%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> **path:** Required string attribute.
>
> Specifies the file path or URL that is served in response to the HTTP
>   error specified by the statusCode and subStatusCode attributes. If you
>   choose the File response mode, you specify the path of the custom
>   error page. If you choose the ExecuteURL response mode, *the path has
>   to be a server relative URL (for example, /404.htm)*. If you choose the
>   Redirect response mode, you have to enter an absolute URL (for
>   example, www.contoso.com/404.htm).

Try changing this line:

```
<error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

To this:

```
<error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/stadtbibliothek/error.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should the customErrors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    *
    *
    *
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
     <customErrors mode="On"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```